# Getting Splunk search result directly from Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, splunk, apache-spark-dataset

Small question regarding an integration between Splunk and Apache Spark.

Currently, I am doing a search query in Splunk. The result is quite big. And I am exporting this result as a CSV to share with several teams for downstream work.

Each of the downstream work ended up loading the CSV as part of a Apache Spark job, converting it to DataSet, and doing map reduce on it.

The Spark jobs from each and every teams are different. Therefore, simply plugin each and every teams computation in Splunk directly is not quite scalable.

This is leading us to ask a question, instead of each teams having to download a copy of the CSV, may I ask, if there is an API, or a way to connect to Splunk search result from Apache Spark directly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Splunk does not have an API specifically for Spark.  There is a REST API, a few SDKs, and (perhaps best for you) support for ODBC.  With an ODBC/JDBC driver installed on your Spark server and a few saved searches defined on Splunk, you should be able to export results from Splunk to Spark for analysis.  See https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/splunk-jdbc-apache-spark.rst for more information.